# Erro navegação com jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, navegação

Estou fazendo um site para usar de portfólio e resolvi fazer um menu para navegação. Decidi implementar também uma feature para alterar a cor da li sempre ao rolar o scroll. Ela até estava funcionando, porém depois que dei reolad na página não funcionou mais de jeito algum. Segue o código:

HTML:

```
<nav id="menu-desktop">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" class="mostrarAtivo">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Sobre</a></li>
        <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contato</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
header nav ul li a.mostrarAtivo{
  color: white;
}
```

JS:

```
  var links = $("#menu-desktop a");

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var topScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    links.each(function(){
      var href = $(this).attr("href");
      var el = $(href);
      var posSection = el.offset().top;
      var hSection = el.height();

      if (posSection <= topScroll && (posSection + hSection) > topScroll) {
        links.removeClass("mostrarAtivo");
        $(this).addClass("mostrarAtivo");
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass("mostrarAtivo");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o erro. Eu havia definido um `overflow-x: hidden` no meu css, pra fazer desaparecer a barra de scroll horizontal na versão mobile. Infelizmente isso acabou prejudicando no funcionamento da função.